# VBA Paste Cells Stored in Dictionary to Cells in Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to search a column of cells from one worksheet, find all of the unique values, and then paste those values to a column in another worksheet. So far I have code that creates a dictionary, searches through the desired column, and selects all of the unique values in that column.

```
Function UniqueRequest() As Long

        myReqIDCol = ColSearch("id")

        'Creates a dictionary filled with each unique value in the "TaskIDList" column and counts them to determine how many unique keys are in the document
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            tmp = Cells(i, myReqIDCol).Value
            If Not dic.exists(tmp) Then
                dic.Add tmp, 1
            End If
        Next i

End Function
```

I also have a function that selects the sheet I want to paste the cells to and sets it up so it pastes values into each successive blank cell in the desired column.

```
Function ReqSheet(input_column As Integer, input_value As Long) As Long

        Dim rv As Long

            rv = 1

            Sheets("Request Results").Activate
            Do While Cells(rv, input_column).Value <> ""
                rv = rv + 1
            Loop
            Cells(rv, input_column).Value = input_value

    ReqSheet = input_value

    End Function
```

The issue I have is that I'm not entirely sure how to relate these two. I want to call the ReqSheet function with each value of the dictionary, but everything I've tried has failed. Sorry if this is an easy fix, but I can't really find a good solution from the internet and I'm fairly new to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This code and change the column to whatever you want to use.

```
Function UniqueRequest() As Long

        myReqIDCol = ColSearch("id")

        'Creates a dictionary filled with each unique value in the "TaskIDList" column and counts them to determine how many unique keys are in the document
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            tmp = Cells(i, myReqIDCol).Value
            If Not dic.exists(tmp) Then
                dic.Add tmp, 1
            End If
        Next i

For Each value in dic.keys 
  ReqSheet(4,value)  'I have taken column 4,you can change it to any no you want.      
End Function
```

Comment: I get a "ByRef argument type mismatch" when I run this, but it seems like it should work. Any ideas as to why there's an error?

Comment: Remove input_value as long and keep just input_value since we are passing string not number

Comment: i guess you dont need to pass back the Reqsheet=input_value again into UniqueRequest() remove that as well.

Answer (score 5):

One of the nice things about dictionaries is that you can pull their values and keys out into an array and write it all at once to a range without looping.

```
Sub GetUnique()

    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each rCell In Selection.Cells
        If Not dc.Exists(rCell.Value) Then
            dc.Add rCell.Value, rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Request Results").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dc.Keys), 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(dc.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: The Application.Transpose command works great. I only had to replace 'UBound' function with 'dc.Count' as with Ubound for for example15 items I get 14. Then, the resized Range is by one cell smaller.... With the count function it works for me.

Comment: Good catch @MrZH6. Those zero based arrays always get me.

Answer (score 1):

Something along those lines should work. You just need to replace the `input_column` with the proper variable or method to find the column.

```
Function UniqueRequest() As Long

myReqIDCol = ColSearch("id")

'Creates a dictionary filled with each unique value in the "TaskIDList" column and counts them to determine how many unique keys are in the document
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To LastRow
    tmp = Cells(i, myReqIDCol).Value
    If Not dic.exists(tmp) Then
        dic.Add tmp, 1
    End If
Next i


For each _Value in dic

    ReqSheet(input_column, _Value)

Next


End Function
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the _ in front of Value? I get errors if I leave that in there or change it to .Value.

Comment: @user3783788 No, you can change it to any variable name you would prefer. the `_` is just something I'm used to do when not having chosen my variable name.